# Como achar o index de um objeto em uma lista em javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando conseguir o index de um objeto na seguinte lista:

```
let list = [
{nome: joão, idade: 15},
{nome: pedro, idade: 17},
{nome: felipe, idade: 12},
]
```

Porém quando tento usar comando `list.indexOf({nome: felipe, idade: 12})` ele retorna -1

Como posso fazer para conseguir o index de um objeto em uma lista da forma correta?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O método [Array.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) permite encontrar o índice do elemento que satisfaz uma certa condição.

```js
let list = [
    {nome: "joão", idade: 15},
    {nome: "pedro", idade: 17},
    {nome: "felipe", idade: 12},
]
    
let index = list.findIndex(i => i.nome === "felipe" && i.idade === 12);

console.log(index);
```

Comment: Finalmente uma resposta que funcionou! Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

Objetos com o mesmo conteúdo não são iguais, ou seja comparar objetos com igualdade dá sempre diferente a não ser que eles sejam uma referência um do outro.
Isso acontece porque cada objeto é uma instância diferente.

Para clarificar:

```
{foo: '123'} == {foo: '123'} // false
{foo: '123'} === {foo: '123'} // false
const foo = {foo: '123'}; 
const foo2 = foo;
foo === foo2 // true 
JSON.stringify({foo: '123'}) === JSON.stringify({foo: '123'}) // true
```

Ou seja, no teu caso vais ter de comparar por strings, ou procurar por valores de propriedades do objeto como o [G. Bittencourt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/449304/129) referiu.

Em principio podias comparar strings, como no ultimo exemplo em cima... mas isso pode dar problemas se a ordem das propriedades for diferente. Sugiro usares uma função que compara propriedades num dado objeto, mas deves ter em mente que pode se houver 2 objetos com as mesmas propriedades ele irá retornar o primeiro que encontrar.

Usando o [`.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) e passando a verificação para a sua callback:

```js
let list = [
  {nome: 'joão', idade: 15},
  {nome: 'pedro', idade: 17},
  {nome: 'felipe', idade: 12}
];

const getIndexOfObject = (arr, ...props) => arr.findIndex(
    el => props.every(([key, value]) => el[key] === value)
); 

const index = getIndexOfObject(list, ['nome', 'pedro'], ['idade', 17]);
console.log(index); // 1
```

Comment: Dessa forma, comparando os objetos como strings, se o parâmetro passado estivesse na ordem `{ idade: 17, nome: 'pedro' }`, a função retornaria `-1`, não?

Comment: @G.Bittencourt verdade, estava a corrigir isso mesmo. Corrigido agora.

Answer (score 3):

Se você quiser comparar por um objeto diretamente, pode fazer algo assim:

```js
const l = [
  { nome: 'João', idade: 15 },
  { nome: 'Pedro', idade: 17 },
  { nome: 'Felipe', idade: 12 }
];

function findIndex(list, obj) {
  return list.findIndex((current) =>
    Object.keys(current).every((key) => obj[key] === current[key])
  );
}

console.log(findIndex(l, { nome: 'Felipe', idade: 12 })); // 2
```

Lembrando que não irá funcionar com objetos aninhados, já que o comparador `===` não compara objetos por seus valores, mas sim pela referência. Mas não creio que esse seja o seu caso.

Answer (score 2):

Uma alternativa é utilizar a lib [Lodash](https://lodash.com/). Nessa lib existe o método [`_.isEqual()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual) que faz a comparação entre objetos independente da ordem qual suas propriedades foram declaradas.

Para obter o índice no array use o método nativo [`Array.prototype.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) que retorna o índice no array do primeiro elemento que satisfizer a função de teste provida.

```js
let l = [
  {nome: "joão", idade: 15},
  {nome: "pedro", idade: 17},
  {nome: "felipe", idade: 12}
]

function índiceDe(objeto, lista) {
  return lista.findIndex(e => _.isEqual(e, objeto));
}

console.log(índiceDe({nome: "felipe", idade: 12},l))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```